# getting error for Couldn't load plugin class: com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapte

Tags: cucumber, extentreports

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w29hR.png)I am getting below error message for extentreports.cucumber.adapter. I believe it is version issue.. can someone suggest what version should i need to use to work extentreports.cucumber.adapter ?

Comment: io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: Couldn't load plugin class: com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter
at io.cucumber.core.options.PluginOption.loadClass(PluginOption.java:117)
at io.cucumber.core.options.PluginOption.parsePluginName(PluginOption.java:102)
at io.cucumber.core.options.PluginOption.parse(PluginOption.java:86)

Comment: Try [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/tech.grasshopper/extentreports-cucumber5-adapter/1.5.1)